# Verificar se pessoa é maior de idade, em caso afirmativo deletá-la

Tags: mysql, mysqli

Preciso fazer uma consulta em banco de dados MYSQL para verificar se um usuário é maior de idade baseado em sua data de nascimento em relação à data atual.

Em caso de afirmativo o usuário deverá ser deletado da base de dados.

Comment: Aonde está a sua dúvida? O que você já tentou até então?

Comment: A dúvida é que nao sei como comparar a data atual com a data de nascimento para verificar se tem 18 anos ou não rsrs

Comment: Não faço nem ideia de onde começar

Comment: Então sugiro começar vendo o [histórico de buscas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bmysql%5d%20comparar%20datas) aqui do site mesmo, que possui várias perguntas que tratam da diferença entre datas no SQL e com isso você conseguirá ao menos definir um ponto de partida.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primeiro, um exemplo de como obter um valor do tipo data no mysql.

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('2019-04-15', '%Y-%m-%d');
```

Exemplo de obter a diferença entre as data

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,'2002-05-01','2001-01-01');
```

Quanto ao DELETE, pode fazer assim:

```
DELETE FROM suaTabela WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,'2002-05-01',CURDATE()) >=18;
```

É um bom norte. Bons estudos!

Comment: kkk eu teria feito o processo na linguagem de back-end